# Adding global state to my VueJS Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a VueJS Application and I'm trying to add a global state to it, in other words.

I have 2 states

```
   // enums.js
    export default {
      LOADING: 0,
      LOADED: 1
    };
```

The state data is defined in the index.js, then I have two more modules that fetch data from my API.

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever the application is firstly opened, display a loading screen and whenever vuex finishes with it's requests to the API then show the appliaction.

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './auth'
import appdata from './appData.js'
import ENUM from '../enums';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    backEndErrors: [],
    apiState: ENUM.INIT
  },

  getters: {
    backEndErrors: state => state.backEndErrors
  },

  mutations: {
    setErrors (state, errors) {
      state.backEndErrors = errors
    },
    setApiState (state, apiState) {
      state.apiState = apiState;
    },
  },

  actions: {},

  modules: {
    auth: auth,
    appdata: appdata
  }
})
```

Here are the two modules

auth.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    userData: null
  },

  getters: {
    user: state => {
      return state.userData
    },
    isLogged: state => {
      return state.userData !== null
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    setUserData (state, user) {
      state.userData = user
    }
  },

  actions: {
    getUserData ({ commit }) {
      axios
        .get('user')
        .then(response => {
          commit('setUserData', response.data)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
        })
    },
    sendLoginRequest ({ commit }, data) {
      commit('setErrors', {}, { root: true })
      return axios
        .post('login', data)
        .then(response => {
          commit('setUserData', response.data.user)
          localStorage.setItem('authToken', response.data.token)
        })
    },
    sendRegisterRequest ({ commit }, data) {
      commit('setErrors', {}, { root: true })
      return axios.post('register', data).then(response => {
        commit('setUserData', response.data.user)
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', response.data.token)
      })
    },
    sendLogoutRequest ({ commit }) {
      return axios.post('logout').then(() => {
        commit('setUserData', null)
        localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
      })
    },
    sendVerifyResendRequest () {
      return axios.get('email/resend')
    },
    sendVerifyRequest ({ dispatch }, hash) {
      return axios.get('email/verify/' + hash).then(() => {
        dispatch('getUserData')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

appData.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    statusesArray: null
  },

  getters: {
    statuses: state => {
      return state.statusesArray
    }
  },

  mutations: {
    setStatusesData (state, statuses) {
      state.statusesArray = statuses
    }
  },

  actions: {
    getStatusesData ({ commit }) {
      return axios
        .get('task-statuses')
        .then(response => {
          commit('setStatusesData', Object.values(response.data))
        })
        .catch(() => {
          localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
        })
    }
  }
}
```

App.vue

```
    <template>
  <div id="app">
    <Sidebar
    v-if="isLogged"
    :class="{ 'show-sidebar': !isSmallSideBar, 'sidebar-hidden' : !isLogged }"
    @sideBarGrow="isSmallSideBar = false"
    @sideBarShrink="isSmallSideBar = true"
    @logout="logout"
    />
    <DynamicHeader
    :class="{ 'margin-header' : !isSmallSideBar }"
    @toogleSideBar="isSmallSideBar = !isSmallSideBar"
    />
    <div class="content" :class="{ 'margin-content' : !isSmallSideBar }">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import Sidebar from './components/partials/Sidebar/Sidebar.vue'
import DynamicHeader from './components/partials/header/DynamicHeader.vue'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      isSmallSideBar: true
    }
  },

  components: {
    Sidebar,
    DynamicHeader
  },

  mounted () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.getUserData()
    } else {
      this.$router.push('/login').catch()
    }

    this.getStatusesData()
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('auth', ['user', 'isLogged']),
    ...mapGetters('appdata', ['statuses'])
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions('auth', ['sendLogoutRequest', 'getUserData']),
    ...mapActions('appdata', ['getStatusesData']),
    logout () {
      this.sendLogoutRequest().then(() => {
        this.$router.push('/login').catch()
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body > div > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}

.loader {
  display: none !important;
  transition: display ease-in-out 0.5ms;
}

.spinning-loader,
.spinning-loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}
.spinning-loader {
  margin: 60px auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  border-top: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 1.1em solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border-left: 1.1em solid #a5a5a5;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
  animation: load8 1.1s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load8 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
</style>
```

main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueTippy, { TippyComponent } from 'vue-tippy'
import Toast, { POSITION } from "vue-toastification";
// Import the CSS or use your own! TOASTS TODO
// import "vue-toastification/dist/index.css";

/**
 * Bootstrap
 */
import { DropdownPlugin, ModalPlugin, FormSelectPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
// import './assets/css/coreuistyle.css'
// import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
// Add additional themes. Tippy
import "tippy.js/themes/light.css";
import "tippy.js/themes/light-border.css";
import "tippy.js/themes/google.css";
import "tippy.js/themes/translucent.css";

import "../src/assets/scss/app.scss";

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(DropdownPlugin)
Vue.use(ModalPlugin)
Vue.use(FormSelectPlugin)
/**
 * Vue
 */

Vue.use(VueTippy, {
  directive: 'tippy', // => v-tippy
  flipDuration: 0,
  popperOptions: {
    modifiers: {
      preventOverflow: {
        enabled: true,
        hide: false
      }
    }
  }
})
Vue.component('tippy', TippyComponent)

const options /* TOASTS TODO */ = {
  // You can set your default options here
  position: POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
  icon: false,
};
Vue.use(Toast, options);

/**
 * Axios before each call
 * */
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    if (error?.response?.status === 422) {
      store.commit('setErrors', error.response.data.errors)
    } else if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
      store.commit('auth/setUserData', null)
      localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
      router.push({ name: 'Login' })
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  }
)
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  config.headers.common = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
  }
  // Applying the API URL before every single call
  config.url = process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + config.url

  // For PHP Debug purposes
  config.url += '?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM'

  return config
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* CLICK OUTSIDE EVENT */
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
      // here I check that click was outside the el and his children
      if (!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
  },
});

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Where do you add the vuex store to your vue instance?

Comment: In my index.js file I will attach it

Comment: anyone got the solution?